# Extract MongoDB hash _id in string format

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, objectid

How we can extract MongoDB's string '_id' field from generated `_id` in order to be used in aggregation framework?

I know that in PHP it's access-able by using complex variable parsed syntax, e.g `_id->{'$id'}`

Example query: (PHP Syntax)

```
    [
        '$lookup' => [
            'from' => 'authors',
            'localField' => 'authorsID', // It's saved as string instead of ObjectID
            'foreignField' => '_id.$id', // Need to convert from ObjectID to String
            'as' => 'authors_doc'
        ]
    ]
```

Any ideas!?

Comment: Which framework are you using? Will you tell a little more about the scenario?

Comment: @KumarAbinash It's a general question, I have to use `$lookup` stage with string id against a MongoID; unfortunately since types are mismatch, I have to convert both to string format in the run-time.

Comment: could you show us query example?

Comment: @profesor79 an example query has been added!